# Windows Explorer file property does NOT show digital signature info for some system file, why?

Tags: windows, digital-signature

For example, PEauth.sys on Windows 7 and 8.1.

Windows Explorer file property dialog does not show Digital Signature tab for this file, but Sysinternal sigcheck.exe says it is digitally signed.

Can some one tell me why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Read [The Case of the Missing Digital Signatures Tab](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/)

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [this article](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/) ([linked by JosefZ](https://superuser.com/questions/1069442/windows-explorer-file-property-does-not-show-digital-signature-info-for-some-sys#comment1506689_1069442)) says, the Digital Signatures tab only appears if the signature is in the file itself. It's also possible for the signature to be stored in a catalog file, which can be found in `\Windows\System32\catroot`.

The Sysinternals `sigcheck` tool can tell you whether a certain file has an embedded signature. If you give it the `-i` option before the filename, the output will include a `Catalog` line, plus lots more certificate information. Files signed in a catalog will have a `.cat` file named on that line, and files with an embedded signature will have their own filename there. For example, this is the first part of the (very long) output of `sigcheck -i \windows\regedit.exe`:

```
C:\Windows\regedit.exe:
    Verified:   Signed
    Link date:  9:12 PM 10/28/2014
    Signing date:   2:59 AM 11/7/2014
    Catalog:    C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Package_868_for_KB3000850~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.8.cat
```

Therefore, `regedit.exe` has a valid signature stored in that catalog.

Comment: Thank you, but your statements are not very accurate. Using sigcheck v2.01, `-i` option always show `Catalog` line, except that for non-catelog-ed files(e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe`), the Catalog line shows the exe file itself.

Comment: @JimmChen Ah, I'm using v2.20; you might want to [download the latest version of the suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).

Comment: I just download the latest  v2.51 (but MS download page stupidly name it v2.5), and confirmed that it always display the Catalog line. You can try it yourself.

Comment: @JimmChen You're right - they updated it again, wow. I've adjusted my answer to use the newest version.

Comment: I suppose if you only move a system file between Windows OS's it would lose its signature....unless you move its associated catalog file as well?

Answer (score 1):

For files where the Digital Signatures tab does not appear because the signature is located in a catalog file, you can also use `signtool.exe` from the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) to check the signature, by passing the appropriate command line options.

If you have the SDK installed, `signtool` will be at e.g.

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\signtool.exe`

(substitute your SDK version and machine architecture as appropriate.)

Run `signtool` with the `/pa` option to do ordinary Authenticode signature verification, as well as the `/a` option to verify a file that might have a signature in a catalog. For example:

```
> signtool verify /pa /a c:\windows\regedit.exe
0      sha256     RFC3161
Successfully verified: c:\windows\regedit.exe
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, the `/a` option(not `/pa`) of signtool.exe enables reporting digital signature on `regedit.exe`. So I think your initial answer gets confused with the meaning of `/pa` and `/a`.

Comment: @JimmChen Yeah, whoops, I mixed them when I was editing. Fixed. Thanks for the heads up.